# jQuery to include all select element starting with same initials

Tags: jquery

```
<select name="wpcf-others" id="abc" class="myzebra-control myzebra-select">
    <option value="">- select -</option>
    <option value="wpcf-field123">General Work Jobs</option>
    <option value="wpcf-fields--1">Journalist/Editors Jobs</option>
    <option value="wpcf-4868b877-1">Publishing Jobs</option>
    <option value="wpcf-fields-2fb08-1">Others Jobs</option>
</select>
```

I have numerous select elements starting with wpcf-, i would like to construct js so prepend all those option value, followed by choosing the prepended value as default,

```
jQuery(function ($) {
$("select[class^='myzebra-control myzebra-select'],select[class*=' myzebra-control myzebra-select']").prepend('<option value="">- select -</option>');
$("select[class^='myzebra-control myzebra-select'],select[class*=' myzebra-control myzebra-select']")[0].selectedIndex = 0;});
```

the prepend did worked out and prepended the values, but only the first select with name starting with wpcf- is defaultly selected the prepended value,and leave the rest unselected.

Comment: It seems to work: [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/J7PhF/). How does it "not work" for you?

Comment: @DavidThomas should i still include the jQuery(function() at the start of the code?i tried your code but no luck

Comment: Yes, you should still wrap the code in a `$(document).ready(function(){ /* your code here */ });` or equivalent. But, first, does it work for you in the demo? If it does, you've got something else going wrong somewhere. Are there any errors reported in your JavaScript console?

Comment: @Dave,  your example is not working for some browsers as you are referencing jQuery 2 which removed some support for older browsers.   jQuery 1.9 still has that support and it was working when that was used.

Comment: @DavidThomas any help from you please? your code is correct, i need help with the second part http://jsfiddle.net/J7PhF/6/

Comment: So, you want to prepend the new option and then select it so that it's shown in the browser? If so: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/J7PhF/11/).